# Rating Changed event is not firing using grid view asp.net web form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Rating Changed event is not firing using grid view asp.net web form, inside grid view I have used rating control but event is not firing when I will click any rating, I am using bootstrap design.

Below is my code.

```
  <div class="eval-rating">
  <h6 class="pull-left">Your Rating
           <br>
            <a class="eval-help" data-toggle="modal" href="#innovation">Help Text?</a></h6>
              <div class="ratin-main">
           <%-- <img src="rating.png">--%>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <itemtemplate>
             <ajax:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CurrentRating='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Innovation") %>' StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" OnChanged="Rating1_Changed" Tag="10" BehaviorID="RatingBehavior1"></ajax:Rating>
             <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Score"
             ErrorMessage="Rate Innovation" Display="Static" ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidator1_ClientValidate" ForeColor="red"></asp:CustomValidator>
             </itemtemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <h6>
            <asp:Label ID="lblR1NotRated" CssClass="rating_Not" runat="server" Text="Not Rated"
            Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblR1Rated" CssClass="rating" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label></h6>
   </div>
   </div>
```

I also check using press f12 to get any error and got below errors.

```
custom.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mixItUp is not a function
http://localhost:50658/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 Failed    to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:50658/imgs/inner-about.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
browserLink:37 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: TemplateField
```

please help me, why Rating1_Changed is not firing.

My java script code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function CustomValidator1_ClientValidate(source, args) {


         if ($find('RatingBehavior1').get_Rating() != 0) // rating is not zero
         {
             args.IsValid = true;
         }
         else {
             args.IsValid = false;
         }
     }
   </script>
```

Comment: Can you please include `CustomValidator1_ClientValidate`? I'm *assuming* that this is where the errors you've included are coming from. It's likely that these JavaScript errors are stopping the AJAX from firing.

Comment: where I have to include please update your answer. @Santi

Comment: Edit your question to include the client validation... The errors you've included in your question are not coming from the code you included.

Comment: I comment client validation then also coming same issue. @Santi

Comment: I updated my question also please check. @Santi

Comment: I comment the customer validation code then also not firing. @Santi